# Logic App - how to initialize and set multiple variables from JSON?

Tags: azure, automation, azure-sentinel

We have a Logic App for Incidents from Sentinel.
This particular one is when malware is detected, we are initializing a AV Scan using Defender.

Problem we had was that to initialize AV Scan, Machine ID is required.
The entities we had which contain machine ID is in Hosts, so we get hosts entity.
Our hostname is device name customized asset tag, machine ID is under the attribute "AadDeviceID". This was not available to select so we had to do initialize variable and then set variable from JSON Parse to get this variable manually.

Now this works for when we have one alert with one machine related however problem is we can get one alert with multiple devices sometimes and this will only do a scan on the first device ID it comes across.

I think there must be a better way of doing this and for some reason think I've over complicated it in my logic app so if someone can look and advise, we need it do run the scan For Each variable it initializes but problem is we want these variables initialized and set automatically where we have multiple ones depending on the number of hosts affected.

Logic App:

[image: Logic App]

Logic App2:

[image: Logic App2]

This is how i tried to get it to run for multiple device ID's but it wasn't working.

Here is an example of the payload from Get hosts, Device ID required for running scan is under "AadDeviceID"

Logic App Payload:

[image: Logic App Payload]